# Turning multiple lines into one comma separated line

Tags: linux, perl, unix, sed, awk

I have the following data in multiple lines:

```
foo
bar
qux
zuu
sdf
sdfasdf
```

What I want to do is to convert them to one comma separated line:

```
foo,bar,qux,zuu,sdf,sdfasdf
```

What's the best unix one-liner to do that?

Comment: If the solutions below do not produce the required results, e.g. only the last line's content showing, you may have unwanted control characters in your input, e.g. `\r`. You can check that by piping the input to `hd` or `hexdump`. `\r` will (in conjunction with `\n`) produce the two-byte sequences `0a0d`. Fix with `|sed 's/\r//g'`.

Comment: This question is a duplicate, but not all of the answers are.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Using paste command:

```
paste -d, -s file
```

Comment: But how to accomplish that for a variable or a pipe?

Update myself:
Using -s without value
.... | paste -d, -s

Comment: While this works for when one wants to convert newlines (`\n`) into commas, it seems that one cannot use this method if one needs to convert newlines into "`, `" which is required for many other commands.

Comment: @NeoMorfeo You can use a `-` to read from pipe as well.

Ex: `echo -e "1\n2\n3" | paste -d, -s -`

Answer (score 92):

#### file

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
```

#### xargs

```
cat file | xargs
```

#### result

```
aaa bbb ccc ddd
```

#### xargs improoved

```
cat file | xargs | sed -e 's/ /,/g'
```

#### result

```
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
```

Comment: xargs turns multi-line into one line space-separated, then sed replaces all space by ','(or ' ,' if you will use sed -e 's/ /\ ,/g' ( by the way -e can be omited)

Comment: usually xargs is not intended for t but it works :)

Comment: and it more prefer way for every day use insted of the one bellow

Comment: Thanks for the step by step!  I had a file with one entry per line, (fn, ln,id,status, blank line.)  I needed it in CSV, so I swapped "blank line" with an unused symbol (sed -e 's/^$/#/') before using the mod you've explained.

Comment: I found this to be the solution I was looking for, not the accepted one because it works for pipes and multiple files and you can pass it to tr -s " " "\t" if you want to add tabs and so forth.  Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

There are many ways it can be achieved. The tool you use mostly depends on your own preference or experience.

Using tr command:

```
tr '\n' ',' < somefile
```

Using awk:

```
awk -F'\n' '{if(NR == 1) {printf $0} else {printf ","$0}}' somefile
```

Comment: your both commands would generate ending comma

Comment: yes, i can fix it in awk but not in tr, give me a min.

Comment: `awk '{printf NR==1?$0:","$0}' file`

Comment: Never use `printf $0` as it will fail cryptically if $0 contains any printf formatting characters. The synopsis for printf is `printf format, data` so use `printf "%s", $0` instead.

Comment: i still have a lot to learn. thanks

Answer (score 10):

`xargs -a your_file | sed 's/ /,/g'`

This is a shorter way.

Comment: except if there are spaces in your lines...

Comment: sed -e 's/ /+/g' test |xargs|sed 's/ /,/g;s/+/ /g' 
it was just an idea how to use xargs :) do not think it is seriously

Answer (score 8):

based on your input example, this awk line works. (without trailing comma)

```
awk -vRS="" -vOFS=',' '$1=$1' file
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "foo
bar
qux
zuu
sdf
sdfasdf"|awk -vRS="" -vOFS=',' '$1=$1' 
foo,bar,qux,zuu,sdf,sdfasdf
```

Comment: You only need to use `-v` if you want the variables available in the BEGIN block, slightly more concise `awk '$1=$1' RS= OFS=, file`.

Comment: For clarity and to avoid getting surprised when you later do try to use a variable in a BEGIN block, I'd always use -v unless setting a variable to different values between files. FYI omitting the space between -v and the variable name makes your script un-necessarily gawk-specific so I'd use `-v RS=` instead of `-vRS=`.

Comment: @EdMorton thx for the comment. (the "space" between -v and va). I learned many tips from you :). Personally I always use `-v` too.

Answer (score 6):

Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe'chomp, s/$/,/ unless eof' file
```

or, if you want to be more cryptic:

```
perl '-peeof||chomp&&s/$/,/' file
```

Comment: Even more cryptic: `perl '-peeof||s|$/$|,|' file`

Comment: sid_com, I like your choice of substitution delimiters :D... `perl -pe 'eof or s#\n$#,#' thing`

Comment: ok, even more cryptic perl: perl -l54 -pe 'eof and $\=""' file (and you can go with empty script body if you can tolerate last coma)

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n 's/.*/&,/;H;$x;$s/,\n/,/g;$s/\n\(.*\)/\1/;$s/\(.*\),/\1/;$p'
```

Comment: too complicated. Please explain @protist.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pi.bak -e 'unless(eof){s/\n/,/g}' your_file
```

This will create a backup of original file with an extension of .bak and then modifies the original file